# Renesas -- cannot get I/O to work except onboard LED

Tags: c, eclipse, io, embedded

This is regarding an RL78G14 dev board/stick.

At first I initialized the led *D2* using `PM7 = 0x7F;` and I toggled it every 63 ms using a timer ISR with `P7 ^= 80;`.

That went fine. Next step was getting another pin to do the same, but it did not work. I even tried toggling most of the I/O pins using

```
PM7 = 0x0;
PM6 = 0x0;
PM5 = 0x0;
PM4 = 0x0;
PM3 = 0x0;
PM2 = 0x0;
```

and

```
P7 ^= 0xFF;
P6 ^= 0xFF;
P5 ^= 0xFF;
P4 ^= 0xFF;
P3 ^= 0xFF;
P2 ^= 0xFF;
```

. The led still blinks, but about 95% of the 64 pins remain low (GND). (Implying no change in any other pins except P77 (led)).

I'm also using E2 studios v3.0.0.22 (Eclipse based), KPIT compiler v15.02, the built in code generator in e2 studios, and developing in Windows 8 at the moment.

Anyone have an idea how to approach this problem? It doesn't have to be specific to this board. If it were an embedded board you were familiar with, how would you fix it?

Comment: Questions like these, where the problem might be related to hardware just as well as software, are more suitable for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer my own question, it really was trivial in the end. It was a case of improper grounding. I assumed that the scope and board were both grounded, so I measured using only the positive lead of the scope. It does work in the end.